# setting up a mySQL server with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ubuntu-12.04

I tried setting up an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to work as a server for a mySQL database. First of all, I want it to be reached remotely. Since there's a problem with getting a static IP, I used no-ip.com. I don't know it it will work using that site, but I want to give it a try anyways. 
The problem is, I can't really setup the mySQL server to be remotely accessed. I tried and it's always "access denied".
Anyone made something similar but working? I'd really need a simple tutorial on how to set this up. The Ubuntu mySQL documentation seems not to be working that much for me.
Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with sql-server?

Comment: try your hands on mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Build a server instance using"MySql Workbench" its provides easy administration and variety of tools and settings very user friendly.